# Dual Boot Dell Inspiron 7577 Windows SSD and Linux HDD

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I just finally bought a laptop and I am motivated to learn working on linux.

The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7577 that came with two hard disks:

- C: PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD 256GB on which is installed windows 10
- D: HDD 1000GB "Healthy (Primary Partition)"

My idea is to install Ubuntu on a partition of disk D: HDD 1000 GB and use it in dual boot with windows 10.

1) I shrunk the volume D: into two equal sized partitions because I want to install ubuntu 16.04 on the Unallocated partition of HDD D:

2) Then, I downloaded the .iso of Ubuntu and booted it on my usb pen drive using rufus.

3) Restarted the computer and run the ubuntu installer

4) In the page where it is supposed to ask - according to the tutorial [enter link description here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.74544274.1099945012.1519841072-888913064.1519841072#9) - whether to erase the computer, install alongside windows and other options, the page is different and do not allow me to select anything.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Simply shrink the partition to the intended size, in Windows, leaving the rest as unallocated space. The Linux distro installer will do the rest. You can use this as a reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: thank you very much :) and then it will automatically ask me whether I want to run windows or ubuntu at every restart?

Comment: Yes, that's Grub. But... Sometimes it still boots Windows directly - boot priority hasn't been changed by the installer - and in that case you should also open UEFI settings a make Linux (Grub) the first priority.

Comment: actually it is not that straightforward as it appeared. I shrunk the HDD into two partitions equal sized but the ubuntu installed cannot find any disk to install on

Comment: You may need to change the drives mode from RAID to AHCI but before that make sure to install AHCI drivers in Windows otherwise it won't boot.

Comment: so probably is it easier to use a virtual machine instead of messing up with all settings in UEFI?